# Reference for spar parameter in R's implementation of the smoothing spline

Tags: r, references, splines, smoothing

In the R's  implementation of the smoothing spline which is `smooth.spline` function, there is a parameter, called `spar` that controls the smoothing. This parameter is specified as the following function of $\lambda$ which is the regularization parameter for the roughness penalty (the integral of the squared second derivative):
$$
\lambda = r \cdot 256^{3\text{spar} - 1}
$$
where $r = \text{tr}(X'W X)/\text{tr}(\Sigma)$, etc. I refer to [the R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/smooth.spline.html) for the details of the definition of the remaining symbols.

Does anyone have a reference in the literature for where this way of setting smoothness (i.e. spar's definition) was first proposed?